# Can't center column header for a sortable column in a mat-table

Tags: html, css, angular-material, mat-table

I have a mat-table with a sortable column like [this](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting) but I can't center the column headers from my css file. I can do it in the browser debugger!

I tried this below in the css file with no luck, but it works when I modify it in the debugger.

```
.mat-sort-header-container {
   justify-content: center !important;
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qdbzaw `th.mat-header-cell {
    text-align: center;
}` Do you want it like that?

Comment: tried that, doesn't work either

Comment: I am looking an answer for this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
th.mat-header-cell {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: it seems like the mat-table is overriding my css when it renders. but not sure