# How to (right/left/center) align individual column headers in mat-table with mat-sort-header?

Tags: angular-material, text-align, angular-material-table

I'm using Angular 16 with Angular Material 16, and I have designed a table with sortable columns following [the documentation here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting).  Certain columns contain numerical data and I'd like to right-align them.  There are other columns I might like to center-align.  I'm not looking to apply the same horizontal alignment to *all* the columns.

Angular Material automatically generates CSS classes for each column like `.mat-column-<column-name>`, so you can style all the cells in a column.  This works to right-align the numbers in column `foo`:

```
.mat-column-foo {
    text-align: right;
}
```

It even works on the **TH** header cells for that column, at first.  However, after I added sorting to my column, using `mat-sort-header`, the newly generated header is aligned left by default.  This is a typical column definition in my HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="foo">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="Sort by Foo">FOO</th>
    <th mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.foo}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

How can I right-align the sortable header, or center-align another such header?

*Other questions I looked at:*

- *[46154838](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154838/angular-material-2-table-header-center-alignment) about ways to **center**-align **all** the headers.*
- *[59418930](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418930/cant-center-column-header-for-a-sortable-column-in-a-mat-table) is about **center**-aligning only, and doesn't have an answer that applies to the `mat-sort-header` condition.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial answer [from TotallyNewb on question 76505146](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76505146/3938965).  He indicates that "since this happens inside a new component injected through a directive, [a CSS solution] needs to happen in global styles".  Thus, to center-align a column heading, he creates a new style in the global `styles.scss`, and applies it to the **TH** in the component HTML.

Expanding on that answer to add an option for right-align, here is what I added to my global `styles.scss`:

```
.centered-sorted-header {  
  .mat-sort-header-container {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
.right-aligned-sorted-header {  
  .mat-sort-header-container {
    justify-content: end;
  }
}
```

Then, in my component's HTML, I can define a right-aligned and a centered column like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="foo">
    <th class="centered-sorted-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="Sort by Foo">Foo</th>
    <th mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.foo}}</td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="bar">
    <th class="right-aligned-sorted-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header sortActionDescription="Sort by Foo">Bar</th>
    <th mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.bar}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Meanwhile, this CSS in the *component* SCSS file aligns the table elements (other than the header):

```
.mat-column-foo {
    text-align: center;
}
.mat-column-bar {
    text-align: right;
}
```

This works.  If there's a way to do it without affecting *global* styles, so all the code changes stay in the component, that would be preferred.